# How to use gradle Artifactory plugin in gradle subproject

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I have a multi-project gradle build wherein one of the subprojects is applying the Artifactory plugin (version 4.2.0), and configuring the contextUrl and resolve repoKey.

It sets up a simple configuration and dependency entry, and then has a copy task to retrieve the dependency as a zip file and extract it into a directory.

However, when the copy task runs, I get the error below. What am I doing wrong? Is this a problem with the Artifactory plugin, or gradle, or...?

The problem does not appear to be related to whether or not this is a subproject. I get the same error if I remove the multiproject configuration and run the task from the subproject directory.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\hoobajoob\project\subproject\package.gradle' line: 36

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':subproject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':subproject:runtimeDep'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency company.com:artifact-id:1.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
```

Here are the contents of subproject/package.gradle (Artifactory url/user/password properties are in a gradle.properties file for the subproject):

```
plugins {
  id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.2.0"
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    resolve {
        repository {
          username = "${artifactory_user}"
          password = "${artifactory_password}"
          repoKey = 'some-repo'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    runtimeDep
}

dependencies {
    runtimeDep 'company.com:artifact-id:1.0.0@zip'
}

ext.destination = null
task getDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree { configurations.runtimeDep.singleFile }
    into ".artifacts/runtime"
}
```

The root project build script is empty except for the wrapper task. Below is the settings.gradle file:

```
include 'subproject'
rootProject.children.each { project -> project.buildFileName = "package.gradle" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the task setup in my question is different, this appears to be the same symptom as described in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512005/gradle-artifactory-plugin-artifact-resolution-not-working?rq=1).

The problem seems to be related to the fact that the Artifactory plugin will not perform dependency resolution until gradle's execution phase. I had assumed that defining the argument to the `zipTree` step in the `getDependencies` task with a closure would have the effect of deferring the dependency resolution until that phase.

But, for this to be deferred by the copy task, I need to define the `from` configuration of the `getDependencies` task as a closure, and include the `zipTree` operation in that closure.

It's the difference between:

```
from zipTree { configurations.runtimeDep.singleFile } // doesn't work
```

...and

```
from { zipTree( configurations.runtimeDep.singleFile ) } // works
```

Making this change gets the resolve working (with no required maven `repositories` block).

Another solution is to drop the Artifactory configuration altogether (which I can do in this case because I do not need to utilize anything unique to Artifactory) and use the traditional gradle `repositories` block, as described in the other SO question and by [crazyjavahacking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280723/crazyjavahacking). Doing this makes the build script shorter, and I can leave the zipTree step configured as it was originally written:

```
repositories {
   maven {
      url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/repo-key"
   }
}

configurations {
    runtimeDep
}

dependencies {
    runtimeDep 'company.com:artifact-id:1.0.0@zip'
}

ext.destination = null
task getDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree { configurations.runtimeDep.singleFile }
    into ".artifacts/runtime"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Gradle print to the console:

**You did not define `repositories{}` block and so it does not know how to download declared dependency.**

Comment: This is supposed to be the responsibility of the Artifactory plugin. It is documented to be providing support for both resolve and publishing, with no required repositories block. See: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin